# Firefox has stopped working Selenium

Tags: intellij-idea, automation

After upgrading to 38.0.1 version of firefox, I have been getting this issue when I run test suit on intelliJIDEA. This problem didn't persist on 35 version of firefox. View problem details shows as follows:

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
>     Application Name: firefox.exe
>     Application Version:  38.0.1.5611
>     Application Timestamp:    55540a1a
>     Fault Module Name:    xul.dll
>     Fault Module Version: 38.0.1.5611
>     Fault Module Timestamp:   55541969
>     Exception Code:   c0000005
>     Exception Offset: 0035669b
>     OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>     Locale ID:    1033
>     Additional Information 1: 0a9e
>     Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>     Additional Information 3: 0a9e
>     Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Surprisingly when i click on "Close the program" firefox starts well. Though I cannot keep doing that for automation run.

(it does not let me post image of pop up i am getting)

Selenium Version : 2.45.0
IntelliJIDEA version : 14.0.3

Comment: What is your selenium version?

Comment: Selenium Version : 2.45.0  IntelliJIDEA version : 14.0.3

Comment: That selenium version does not provide support for FF latest version , please check here : https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES

Comment: Thanks! Guess I will have to fall back to 37 as it was working fine on that.

Comment: yup....you are right..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solution of this problem  - 
1) Downgrade your FF version from 38 to 37 
2) Upgraded the selenium version from 2.45 to 2.48.

Answer (score 1):

I too had got this problem and I just reinstalled the selenium and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same behavior as the questioner.  Reinstalling selenium made the problem go away.  As I'm using python, I did this with

- pip uninstall selenium
- pip install selenium

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. However, reinstalling selenium did not work for me. Therefore I upgraded Firefox from 47.0 to 47.0.1 and it worked. The details are below.

- OS: Windows 7 Home Basic SP 1
- Selenium version: 2.53.6
- Firefox version: 47.0.1 (Upgraded from 47.0)